# Modify polygon in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

Here is the next function to select and modify the selected polygons. I have an error in var "vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector": missing: after property id. that someone are correcting my code and giving me a solution of ​​how polygons can be modified

```
Function ModifySnappingZone(MapIdentifier){

  var selectf = new ol.interaction.Select({
      var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector(

    layers:[vectorLayer],     
     }); 
   map.addInteraction(selectf); 


  selectf.on('select', function(evt) {

//here I want to modify the polygone (deform)
}); 
}
```

---

```
//function draw(works already):
function DrawSnappingZone(MapIdentifier){
        var coordinatearray = [];
        var snappingpoints = prompt("Wieviele Punkte sollen gesetzt werden?");
        MapIdentifier.on('click', function(evt)
        {
            var single_coordinate = ol.proj.toLonLat(evt.coordinate);
            coordinatearray.push(single_coordinate);
            //console.log(coordinatearray);
            console.log(coordinatearray.length);
            //DrawSnappingZone(coordinatearray, 5);
            if (coordinatearray.length == snappingpoints)
            {   
                coordinatearray.push(coordinatearray[0]);
                RouteAnzeigenAusKoordinaten(coordinatearray, KarteGlobal_o, 'red');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define vector layer before you can use it in select definition.

Your select definition contains only first statement of vector layer definition, and it's also in the wrong place. First define layer outside select definition, then use it in select definition:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector(
  // vector layer defintion options
);

var selectf = new ol.interaction.Select({
  layers:[vectorLayer]
});
```